# finding duplicates and updating a column with values according with number of duplicates using mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursors

I am using Mysql 10.1.29-MariaDB Database to create a new table.

What I am trying to do is to increment a number for each duplicate appearance of a value of company_name in another column. For example, for the table:

provided order_placed column of both table should be null

```
# req 


+--------------------------------------------------+
|                        req                       |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| req_id | order_placed | contact_id | seq_records |
+--------+--------------+------------+-------------+
| 1      |         null |       1000 |        null |
+--------+--------------+------------+-------------+
| 2      |         null |       1002 |        null |
+--------+--------------+------------+-------------+
| 3      |         null |       1003 |        null |
+--------+--------------+------------+-------------+



+-------------------------------------------------------+
|                               contact                 |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| contact_id | first_name | order_placed | company_name |  
+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
| 1000       | dirt       |         null |         Asus | 
+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
| 1002       | dammy      |         null |         Asus | 
+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
| 1003       | samii      |         null |         Asus | 
+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
| 1004       | xenon      |         null |       Lenova | 
+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+


CREATE TABLE `req` (
  `req_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   `order_placed` char(1) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
   `contact_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   `seq_records` bigint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`req_id`),
  KEY `contact_id` (`contact_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `req_ibfk_10` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`) REFERENCES 
  `contact` (`contact_id`)
) 
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

# contact

CREATE TABLE contact (
  contact_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `company_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_id` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_placed` char(1) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`contact_id`),
  KEY `index_name` (`contact_id`),
)
```

## query used

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `recordsequence` $$
CREATE procedure `recordsequence` ()
BEGIN

declare companyname varchar(250);
declare recordcount integer default 0;
declare duplcount integer default 0;
DECLARE vfinished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
declare icount int default 0;
DEClARE records_cursor CURSOR FOR
select c.company_name,count(c.company_name),r.opr_id from contact c, request r where c.contact_id=r.contact_id and r.order_placed is null  group by c.company_name;
-- declare NOT FOUND handler
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER
FOR NOT FOUND SET vfinished = 1;
OPEN records_cursor;
transfer_records: LOOP
FETCH records_cursor INTO companyname,duplcount;
IF vfinished = 1 THEN
LEAVE transfer_records;
END IF;

begin
set recordcount := duplcount;
set icount := 1;
DEClARE records_cursor1 CURSOR FOR
select c.contact_id,c.company_name from contact c, request r where c.company_name = companyname and c.contact_id=r.contact_id and r.order_placed is null group by c.company_name;
-- declare NOT FOUND handler
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER
FOR NOT FOUND SET vfinished = 1;
OPEN records_cursor1;
transfer_records1: LOOP
FETCH records_cursor INTO contactid,companyname;
IF vfinished = 1 THEN
LEAVE transfer_records1;
END IF;

begin

UPDATE contact set reorder_sequence = icount where contact_id = contactid;
set icount := icount + 1;
end;

END LOOP transfer_records1;

CLOSE records_cursor1;

if(recordcount == icount) THEN

select concat('company_name Updated successfully', companyname);

else
select concat('company_name count mismatches please check', companyname);
end if

end

END LOOP transfer_records;

CLOSE records_cursor;

End$$
DELIMITER ;
```

the above query is to create a procedure for the steps below

1. To fetch records companyname and duplcount of the company names with the
   cursor.
2. To fetch contact id of each company names and start a loop for a update
   statement.
3. To update `reorder_sequence` table with values like the example given below

## expected Result

```
Eg:  contact table

+--------------------------------------------------------+
|                         contact                        |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| order_placed | contact_id | company_name | seq_records |
+--------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| null         |       1002 |         Asus | 1           |
+--------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| null         |       1003 |         Asus | 2           |
+--------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| null         |       1005 |         Asus | 3           |
+--------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| null         |       1006 |       Lenova | 1           |
+--------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Like the above example i have updated seq_records column with values according to the company_name column provided both order_placed column is null

## error

A syntax error occurred with code 1064 near second select statement.

Comment: When you say reorder_sequence, do you mean seq_records? Instead of ASCII art tables. use INSERT statements. I can only speak for myself, but having to create insert statements myself is a showstopper for trying to answer a question.

Answer (score 0):

`==` is not used; use just a single `=`.

All `DECLAREs` must come before the code.

When asking about 1064, always include the entire error message.  The "near..." is usually an excellent clue of where the error occurred.

Comment: near `Delcare records_cusor1 Cursor FOR`

Comment: `SET` statements are sitting before `DECLARE`, so my second statement applies.  The `near` pointed to the right spot but did not say why it is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

analytical / window functions :) pls do not reinvent a wheel :)

```
CREATE TABLE `req` (
  `req_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   `order_placed` char(1) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
   `contact_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   `seq_records` bigint(2) DEFAULT NULL
) 
;


CREATE TABLE contact (
  contact_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `company_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_id` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_placed` char(1) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL
) ;

INSERT INTO req VALUES (1, NULL, 1000, NULL);
INSERT INTO req VALUES (2, NULL, 1002, NULL);
INSERT INTO req VALUES (3, NULL, 1003, NULL);

INSERT INTO contact VALUES (1000, 'dirt','Asus', 12, NULL);
INSERT INTO contact VALUES (1002, 'dammy', 'Asus', 12, NULL);
INSERT INTO contact VALUES (1003, 'samii', 'Asus', 12, NULL);
INSERT INTO contact VALUES (1004, 'xenon', 'Lenova', 1, NULL);
```

select:

```
SELECT order_placed
, contact_id
, company_name
, row_number() over (partition by company_name order by contact_id) as seq_records
FROM contact;
```

result:

```
| order_placed | contact_id | company_name | seq_records |
| ------------ | ---------- | ------------ | ----------- |
|              | 1000       | Asus         | 1           |
|              | 1002       | Asus         | 2           |
|              | 1003       | Asus         | 3           |
|              | 1004       | Lenova       | 1           |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) (make sure you select MySQL 8 .. v5 does not support window functions

Comment: i got a error near row_number() `over (`